# maven exec plugin exception

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am getting following exception. How do I know which command is failing and why?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (XYZ) on project ABC: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (XYZ) on project ABC: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:352)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Launching Maven with debug output (-X), you should see the exact command launched, which will greatly help investigating that external command error.

Comment: It already has -X flag.

Comment: The important thing here is: `exec (XYZ) on project ABC: Command execution failed. ` and  ` Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127)` ? What are you trying to execute? Running on windows/linux OS? Which Maven version? What kind of command do you try to execute?